# Why does .getComponent().getValue() return null while can be accessed in CSJS?

Tags: jsf, xpages, ssjs

I have an input field of type password just like this:

```
    <xp:td id="passwordInputTd" align="right">
        <xp:inputText id="passwordInputValue" password="true">
        </xp:inputText>
    </xp:td>
```

When I try to get the value in SSJS like this:

```
<xp:button id="signInButton"
                    styleClass="prettyEGRZButton prettyEGRZButtonActive"
                    style="width: 50%; padding: 10px;" value="Sign In" />
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                    console.log("CSJS value: " + document.getElementById("#{id:passwordInputValue}").value);
                    ]]></xp:this.script>

                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:              
                    var passwordValue = getComponent('passwordInputValue').getValue());
                    }]]>
                    </xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
```

It returns null for no good reason.

The interesting part here that it works as expected in the snippet

```
console.log("CSJS value: " + document.getElementById("#{id:passwordInputValue}").value);
```

I get it printed in CSJS, but in SSJS it's almost always null (but not always!)

What's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try getComponent('passwordInputValue').getSubmittedValue()

Comment: Didn't work :( Is there any way to directly set this component's value in CSJS?

Comment: I would recommend NOT to use getValue(). Bind the control to a scoped variable and access that one.